# Call two functions in one click

Tags: html, onclick

Is it possible to call two functions in one click in html?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="user-list"
 (click)="threadService.createChatWindow()"
 (click)="matrixService.newRoom(thread)">
</div>
```

It does not work

Comment: It would be better that a single click event calls a single method that, in turn, can decide what other related action(s) need to be taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two attributes, instead combine with `;`:

```
<div class="user-list"
 (click)="threadService.createChatWindow(); matrixService.newRoom(thread)">
</div>
```